# Struts2 - datepicker client-side validation returns same error message twice

Tags: jquery, validation, struts2, datepicker

I use a struts2 form with datepicker:

```
<s:form action="%{#parameters.myAction}" namespace="/" method="post" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" focusElement="dealTitleId" validate="true">
...
<sj:datepicker name="dealDisplayEnd" required="true" key="dealDisplayEnd-label" displayFormat="dd-mm-yy" readonly="true" minDate="0"/>
```

Please note the `validate="true"` option which enables the client-side validation (I need this to prevent losing some other information about file upload when some error occurs).

Then also created the XML for it:

```
<field name="dealDisplayEnd">
        <field-validator type="required">
             <message key="error.dealDisplayEnd.empty"/>
        </field-validator>
  </field>
```

Everything works fine, except that the error is repeated twice:

[image: Error is shown twice]

Looking at the web page source, I see that the validation script is generated twice:

```
 // field name: dealDisplayEnd
        // validator name: required
        if (form.elements['dealDisplayEnd']) {
            field = form.elements['dealDisplayEnd'];
            var error = "Deal display end date must be provided!";
            if (field.value == "") {
                addError(field, error);
                errors = true;

            }
        }
        // field name: dealDisplayEnd
        // validator name: required
        if (form.elements['dealDisplayEnd']) {
            field = form.elements['dealDisplayEnd'];
            var error = "Deal display end date must be provided!";
            if (field.value == "") {
                addError(field, error);
                errors = true;

            }
        }
```

Is this a struts2 bug? Or am I doing something wrong? Is it because I'm using datepicker and client-side validation? I'm using struts2-core-2.3.4.jar and struts2-jquery-plugin-3.3.3.jar.
Is there an easy way for me to patch (I could not locate the place where this is generated)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, it seems be a bug from `struts2-jquery-plugin`. here are some references:

[REFERENCE 1](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=626)
[REFERENCE 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744773/html-form-being-submitted-twice-via-submit-click-trigger)

the advice from the author of `struts2-jquery-plugin`:

`In this case you should not set validate="true". Implement you own validation handling in an own onBeforeTopic. How it works can you see in the struts2 jquery sources.`

I guess you are using `<sj:submit/>`, you can try to use `<s:submit/>` if you are not using the property `targets`, it may fix your problem. There are more ways to fix this problem, just try it by yourself, if you can't accomplish it, let us know.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I'm already using `<s:submit/>`. I'll disable client-side validation and implement my own for this field.

Comment: Leaving the problem opened in case some other answers are provided.